# Is Gmail stopping rules in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, gmail, mail-rules

My rules in Mail.app works only when I run them manually. I gues this should not be a case. Rules should work on each sync. On https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mail/mlhlp1017/mac I have found

> Mail stops applying rules to a message when it encounters the Stop Evaluating Rules action, or when a message is transferred to another mailbox by rules used on a mail server or computer or device synced to your computer.

Could be Gmail who prevents rules to start?

Comment: Are you also checking your mail from another device?  On macOS, Mail rules only apply to unread mail.  If you read mail on your iPhone before downloading mail on the Mac, rules don't get automatically applied.

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks, that could be the thing.